# What is the best way to communicate between two process with C#?

Tags: c#

use net remoting or others ??

I want sample way, I think that no socket or other would be more easy to deploy ...

anyway ,help please , thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to begin with Namedpipes.

Since you are dealing with C#, have a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx

Essentially, this got me going instantly when I was looking into it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx#Y1920

Good luck.

Comment: Named pipes is perhaps the most direct route.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do.  If you just want to send notifications between two processes running on the same computer, named events work just fine.  If you want to send long messages, then there are named pipes, sockets, and WCF (which replaces .NET Remoting).  You might also want to share memory with memory mapped files.  There are several other possibilities.

The method you use depends in large part on how much data you want to communicate, how fast you need it to be, and how much time you want to spend futzing with it.